# Old password, New password logic

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to develop a functionality where I want to check any user who changes his password, should not be able to again enter the same password in the New password field. Please see the  code for your reference and let me know what can I do to add that functionality.

```
 <tr>
            <td class="a1">Old Password</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtOldPassword" runat="server" CssClass="form_txtfld"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="a1">New Password</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtNewPassword" runat="server" CssClass="form_txtfld"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="a1">Confirm Password</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPassword" runat="server" CssClass="form_txtfld" ></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"  onclick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" style="width: 63px;" />&nbsp;
                <input type="reset" runat="server" name="Reset" style="width: 63px;" />
            </td>
```

Code behind for the same:-

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    String LoginID = Session["user"].ToString();
    String OldPassword = txtOldPassword.Text.Trim();
    String LoginPassword = txtNewPassword.Text.Trim();

    if (OldPassword != Session["password"].ToString())
    {
        String sc = "<Script>alert('Old Password does not match')</script>";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "Ad" + DateTime.Now, sc, false);
    }
    else
    {
        LoginLogic _LoginLogic = new LoginLogic();
        _LoginLogic.ChangePassword(LoginID, LoginPassword);
        //Exit the current session
        Session.Abandon();
        String sc = "<Script>alert('You have successfully changed your password. Please login again.');location.href='default.aspx'</script>";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "Ad" + DateTime.Now, sc, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: So can you suggest me anything better for this. Any logic will he helpful

Comment: `Session["password"]` -> something is already **wrong**. You should not have the password available as plain text.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are hashing the passwords, I do hope you are not storing them in clear text!

Comment: @TrevorPilley: No not storing them,

Comment: For that campare the values Session["password"].ToString() and new Password. And If you want to keep track of all of the old passwords the user enters add fields in the db

Comment: @Dr Schizo 'Oh my dear using script manager and composing JavaScript in the code behind not a great idea.' - Why, what is wrong with writing some javascript dynamically?

Comment: @MartinSmellworse, I consider it a bad idea as composing JavaScript server side is a client concern. Mixing the two together will only introduce a 'ball of mud' and additional unneeded complexity. For example, if I saw JavaScript executed on a page I would firstly examine the JavaScript files and not troll through server side code. To achieve what OP is doing, you would simply use ASP.NETs native validation support http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refvalidationcontrols.asp

Comment: Check about validators. Compare validators will do this job

Comment: @partha: can you give an example, or explain how it will work

Comment: Compare validators evaluate the value of one field against a fixed value or another field. Go through this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw(v=vs.71).aspx .
And this too:
http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/compare-validator/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you want is:

*EDIT*

For simplicity sake I added the bit to your code which performs the check. I don't warrant this approach as you are storing a password as plain text in a session variable. However, I imagine this is a school project or something thus security is not a concern really.

```
        string LoginID = Session["user"].ToString();
        string OldPassword = txtOldPassword.Text.Trim();
        string LoginPassword = txtNewPassword.Text.Trim();

        if (OldPassword != Session["password"].ToString())
        {
            String sc = "<Script>alert('Old Password does not match')</script>";
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "Ad" + DateTime.Now, sc, false);
        }
        else if (string.Equals(OldPassword, LoginPassword)) //THIS LINE HERE
        {
            //Old password matches new password
        }
        else
        {
            LoginLogic _LoginLogic = new LoginLogic();
            _LoginLogic.ChangePassword(LoginID, LoginPassword);
            //Exit the current session
            Session.Abandon();
            String sc = "<Script>alert('You have successfully changed your password. Please login again.');location.href='default.aspx'</script>";
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "Ad" + DateTime.Now, sc, false);
        }
```

Comment: it never actually checks that what I assume is a textbox containing the old password is actually the password being used (wasn't my downvote) - I assume the downvote is because of the lack of security

Comment: Isn't suitable for ASP.NET? You smoking crack? Its C#! OP wants to check if the new password typed in matches the old one, that's all hardly rocket science. Look at the markup, its asking the user to input there old password (txtOldPassword) and new password as well as a confirm password, all user inputs.

Comment: My original comment didn't realise op is already attempting something like this. Either way - lack of security and it doesn't check that the old password has actually been entered correctly

Comment: Yeah granted, however security isn't his concern. It could be a school project not something for MI-6. The question doesn't note anything about encryption etc.

Comment: Thanks @DrSchizo: It worked. I will make that textboxes as password for three of them. Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem, glad to be of some help. Not sure who down voted me in the first place flaming nut jobs, ARGH! :@

Answer (score 0):

```
String actualOld = Session["password"].ToString();
String OldPassword = txtOldPassword.Text.Trim();
String LoginPassword = txtNewPassword.Text.Trim();
if(actualOld!=OldPassword || LoginPassword==actualOld || LoginPassword==OldPassword  ){
      //error
}
```

*But the Simplest Logic is compare validator with your new and old password text box.*